# fetched json data Dictionary or array is empty in viewdidload or tableview datasource?

Tags: swift

I want to add strings from an array of dictionary from backend.
but it's always empty outside the fetch function

```
//fetch data
func fetchFaqs(){
    let manager = APIManager()
    manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.faqs) { (JSON, Status) in
        if Status {
            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let data = dict!["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
            self.faqs = data as! [[String : String]]
        }
    }
}
//Viewdidload
class FaqViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var faqs = [[String:String]]()
    var questions = NSMutableArray()
    var answers = NSMutableArray()

    @IBOutlet var faqsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchFaqs()
        self.faqsTableView.reloadData()
        print(faqs)
        //        faqsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        //        faqsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
    }
}
```

Comment: In which class you have fetchFaqs method?

Comment: same class where fetch func is

Comment: is fetchFaqs() a method of FaqViewController class? secondly, fetchFaqs() is an asynchronous call, you need to wait for the call to finish before you expect value in self.faqs

Comment: No. You have fetchFaqs() method outside the FaqViewController class

Comment: no its not...its re arranged here for the sake of better understanding..please trust me

Comment: you are not waiting until the  manager.parsingGet returns, you need to add a completion block to your function and access data from that completion block instead of modifying a global variable

Comment: @JaseelCalicut which array do you use in tableview number of rows method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload the tableview inside the api call closure in Main thread

```
func fetchFaqs(){
    let manager = APIManager()
    manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.faqs) { (JSON, Status) in
        if Status {
            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let data = dict!["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
            self.faqs = data as! [[String : String]]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.faqsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JaseelCalicut When you print the array in viewDidLoad it will be empty even after you called fetch function. Fetch function receives a response in asynchronous call. It will receive response after the fetch function is called and the print statement is completed. So update the fetch function as I've said and print array in numberofrows method

Comment: your code doesnt work...as i said i just want to print the array anywhere in the code...so whats the point of reloading tableview ...its unrelated.. please think

Comment: @JaseelCalicut I thought you are using this array in tableview.That's why I asked which array do you use in tableview number of rows method.